# How to invoke a function at a trigger point?

Tags: scrollmagic

When a trigger point is reached, I just want to call a function or run a few statements to do something, which has nothing to do with interface. Here is how I am doing now for this purpose:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#some-trigger", triggerHook: 'onLeave', offset: })
   .on('start', function () {

    // statements go here

    }).addTo(controller);
```

Is this the correct way?

The reason to ask this question is that I find out Scroll Magic can be a UNIQUE event control tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little later but I jump to that question because I had the same issue in some projects.

So i solved in two ways:

Using `enter` or `progress` event

[**ENTER**](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:enter) is trigger when a scene is starting. It's depends on `triggerHook`

```
scene.on("enter", function (event) {
   console.log("Scene entered.");
});
```

[**PROGRESS**](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:progress) is trigger every time

```
scene.on("progress", function (ev) {
    if( ev.progress > 0.25){
       //== going farward
    }
    if(ev.progress < 0.25){
      //== going backward
    }
})
```